# Is multiple root level directories upload possible with webkitdirectory?

Tags: html, forms, file-upload, upload, multifile-uploader

We have recently developed a mass uploader that uses the [`webkitdirectory`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/webkitdirectory) functionality in order to be able to upload directories and parse all inner files.

However the uploading of multiple root directories is not possible even after using `multiple` attribute.

In [Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/webkitdirectory), `multiple` is mentioned & used in the examples.

> In this example, a directory picker is presented which lets the user choose one or more directories. When the change event occurs, a list of all files contained within the selected directory hierarchies is generated and displayed.

But basically is useless. With or without `multiple` produces the same result. We're only able to select 1 directory.

How can we have the `input` with `webkitdirectory` allow us to select multiple directories? I would truly appreciate any ideas or hacks.

Comment: Shy of adding many inputs, each with the webkitdirectory attribute set, each uploading just one directory... I don't see this happening. Sounds like you'd be better off getting the user to zip up the files they care about, or piggyback on something like Dropbox that you can drop directories of files into within your OS.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: No, not yet but we had found some workaround (non-related to this)